# belongs_to association not populating user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had two models and wanted to add a belongs_to association. A user has_many Places. To do this I did the following:

1) Created a migration using `rails g migration AddUserToPlace user:references`

This created a `user_id` column in my `places` table with the following migration:

```
add_reference :places, :user, index: true
```

However when I create new places the `user_id` column remains blank.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

`create` action

```
def create
  @place = Place.new(place_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @place.save
      format.html { redirect_to @place, notice: 'Place was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @place }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @place.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The user_id is not filled by default. When create new Places make sure to include the `user_id` in the parameters for example;

```
@place = Place.new();
@place.create(name: "jahn", user_id: @current_user.id)
```

Also try to enforce the presence of `user_id` in the `PlaceModel`

```
validates :user_id, presence: true
```

you should have something like this;

```
def person_params
  params.require(:place).permit(:user_id, :..., :....)
end

`User_id` should be passed from the form. Otherwise for example you could do this;
def create
    @place = Place.new(place_params)
    @place.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @place.save
        format.html { redirect_to @place, notice: 'Place was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @place }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @place.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: You should also be able to do @place.create(name: "jahn", user: @current_user)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I have updated the question to include my def create. Place.new() seems to be passed a place_params.

Comment: How do I enforce presense of user_id in place model?

Comment: @Cookiejest, i have updated to show enforcement. Now share the form creating places to make sure it is added to the params sent.

Comment: @Acacia thanks! I still dont understand how i'm meant to pass user_id unless I put it in the form which I don't really want to do?

Comment: @Cookiejest, i have made another change to the answer.

Comment: @Acacia thanks again. place.user_id = current_user.id. That seemed to work within the create method